# Modify styling options for holoviews sankey graph

Tags: holoviews

Is it possible to modify Node style in a holoviews (v 1.10.4) Sankey diagram backed by bokeh (v 0.12.16)? I am setting the node_line_color using the options method (also tried via %%opts in Jupiter notebook) however it is ignored and I see a black outline (default) instead of the white I specify. Only the node_width attribute seems to work but all other node styling attributes are ignored.

```
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv

hv.extension('bokeh')
edges = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
hv.Sankey(edges).options(node_line_color='white')
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs are horrible, but I've discovered you probably want to do this:

```
sankey = hv.Sankey(edges)
sankey.opts(label_position='left', node_width=30)
```